# socket.io - broadcast to certain users

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I need to build twosome chat, using websockets (socket.io + node.js).
So, the simple example to broadcast message to all users:

```
socket.on('user message', function (msg) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('user message', socket.nickname, msg);
  });
```

But how can I broadcast it from certain user to certain user?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are two possibilites :

**1)** Each socket has its own unique ID stored in `socket.id`. If you know the ID of both users, then you can simply use

```
io.sockets[id].emit(...)
```

**2)** Define your own ID (for example user's name) and use

```
socket.join('priv/John');
```

in `connection` handler. Now whenever you want send message only to `John`, you simply do

```
socket.broadcast.to('priv/John').emit(...)
```

**Side note:** the first solution provided cannot be scaled to multiple machines, so I advice using the second one.

Comment: I'm storing users in MySQL with rails, so, how can I relate user ids from db to socket ids?

Comment: small q: is adding a user to multiple rooms (using `join`) can make a load on the server?

Comment: @MarkPegasov sorry for this late response. You have to map concrete sockets to user ids. For that you need some authentication mechanism.

Comment: @Shlomi yes, almost everything you do will use up some resources. However in this concrete case the performance hit should be negligible. Always measure though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `socket.join(...)` function to provide groups:

```js
socket.on('init', function(user) {
  if (user.type == 'dog') {
    socket.join('dogs');
  }
  else {
    socket.join('cats');
  }
});

...

io.to('dogs').emit('food', 'bone'); // Only dogs will receive it
io.to('cats').emit('food', 'milk'); // Only cats will receive it
```

Comment: Nice example here